# Is the Dirac Lagrangian a 4-vector?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-equation, invariants

I was under the impression that the Lagrangian outputs the energy, which is a real-valued scalar.

However, the Dirac Lagrangian seems to read as a 4-vector:

$$
L= \overline{\psi} (i\hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m) \psi
$$

Does the term $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu$ makes $L$ a 4-vector?

Comment: It contracts with $\partial_\mu$.

Comment: The classical Dirac spinor $\psi$ is an Grassmann odd object. It's not ordinary complex valued functions.

Answer (score 4):

The Dirac Lagrangian is actually a Lorentz scalar. Remember that $\psi$ is a 4-component spinor and $\bar \psi=\psi^ \dagger \gamma^0$, so everything is contracted nicely such that $L$ is just a scalar.

This must in fact be the case for the theory to be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: The classical Dirac spinor $\psi$ is an Grassmann odd object. Its Lagrangian density is Grassmann even. It's not an ordinary scalar function.